# CORS Headers in Azure App Service running Express JS

Tags: node.js, azure, express, cors

I'm building a simple web application which has to Cross Origin Resource Sharing restricted to some sites. The app is running in the Azure cloud on an App Service. Right now I have set the CORS headers from both the Azure portal and the Express server app as a middleware in the following way:

`app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});`

My question is, that can I remove the CORS headers from the Express App and use only the headers which are provided by the Azure App Service? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Tyhjis, any update yet?

Comment: Hi @AaronChen-MSFT. I removed the CORS headers from the Node application and it worked. Thank you :)

Comment: My pleasure. If you think this answer below is beneficial for you as well as for others please mark it as correct :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, definitely you can achieve it either by setting CORS headers from the Azure portal or by adding CORS headers from your App.

For other people’s convenience, here I also provide the following steps to set CORS header from the Azure portal.

1. Navigate to the [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com).
2. Navigate to your App Service.
3. Click **CORS** in the **API** menu.
4. Enter each URL in the empty **ALLOWED ORIGINS** text box. A new text box is created.
5. Click **Save**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

They don't recommend to use both
[image]