# Error post request angular 1.x using 'Content-Type': 'application/json'

Tags: angularjs, json, azure, ionic-framework

Previously I used the following type of headers in my function to make the request from the application:

#### Error

> OPTIONS http://API_URL 405 (Method Not Allowed)
>
> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://API_URL. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://192.168.1.9:8100' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.

#### Data Login

```
datos = {
          Usuario: $scope.usuariotxt,
          Password: $scope.passwordtxt
        };
```

`'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`

#### function

```
 function Autenticacion(datos) {


    var url = 'http://API_URL';

    return $http.post(url, $httpParamSerializer(datos), {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    });

};
```

Now the content-type must be different from how you submitted the request in advance

`'Content-Type': 'application/json'`

function Autenticacion(datos) {

```
    //var url = 'API_URL';        

    return $http.post(url, $httpParamSerializer(datos), {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    });

};
```

But using the ARC tool, the request works perfectly

[image: Image Link]

The server is in Azure, this the information

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 270
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-Aspnet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Set-Cookie: ARRAffinity=0a3517ba6ed8bb14ffe517099672a3eb4ea3c4b710ad8c6e0edaa70c2d244335;Path=/;Domain=apipedroupc20170125045931.azurewebsites.net
Date: Tue, 28 Feb 2017 20:53:09 GMT
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource)

Comment: Why are you setting the content-type to `application/json` yet still sending data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?

Comment: @Phil I also feel a little strange, and not only that, it also tells me that the type of petition is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Seems this is a cross domain issue. For security reasons, browsers restrict cross-origin HTTP requests initiated from within scripts. No others implement this restriction, so it's ok for the ARC tool.

You can configure CORS in the [Azure portal](http://portal.azure.com).
For more info, please see my earlier post from Stack Overflow: [CORS Headers in Azure App Service running Express JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40929114/cors-headers-in-azure-app-service-running-express-js/40966606#40966606or), or Azure's documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-api/app-service-api-cors-consume-javascript.